# How to store a function-wrapped solve call?

Tags: matlab, function

Bear with me please, I'm completely new to matlab. I am attempting to store the call to `eigenvalue` in another function, but it's giving me the error: `Too many output arguments`.

```
function eigenvalue(M)
    syms l;
    eq = det(M - l*[1 0; 0 1]);
    solve(eq == 0)
end
```

I've tried storing it in many different ways, but nothing seems to work:

```
>> a = eigenvalue(M)
Error using eigenvalue
Too many output arguments.

>> [a, b] = eigen(M)
Error using eigenvalue
Too many output arguments.
```

The weird thing is that if I solve a normal polynomial equation I can do `sol=solve(x^2==4)` just fine and access `sol(0)`and `sol(1)`without any problems. I guess that I haven't picked up on a simple matlab concept and thanks to anyone who's willing to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have any output arguments in your function.

```
function eigenvalue(M)
```

In MATLAB, you *should** use the following syntax:

```
function output = func_name(input_1,input_2,...)
```

You have 2 alternatives:

You can skip the first line and save it as script, as this:

```
syms l;
eq = det(M - l*[1 0; 0 1]);
solve(eq == 0)
```

Or, you can save it as a function, but with output variable(s), like this:

```
function output = eigenvalue(M)
    syms l;
    eq = det(M - l*[1 0; 0 1]);
    output = solve(eq == 0)
end
```

*You *should* use the syntax I described, but you *can* use the syntax you used as well. However, if you do, the function won't give you anything back except possibly printing the result to screen. You will not get to use any variables created inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to provide an output argument then you have to declare it in the function definition. E.g.

```
function a = eigenvalue(M)
```

You then need to make sure you assign a value to each output variable in the function body.